# how to add header based on condition in jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery

How should I add header based on condition in jQuery Ajax call-

```js
if(true)
    AddHeaderInCall("Header","Value")
else
    DonotAddHeaderInCall()
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a `headers` object and pass it in:

```
var headers = {};
if (something) headers = { myHeader: myValue };

$.ajax({
    headers: headers,
    ..
});
```

Comment: I already have headers object like - headers={'a':1,'b:2'}.. In this ,I need to add new one, based on codition..

Comment: @user3359453 -- Set them all in this `headers` object and add to it then.

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone else who is in searching for doing the same thing, here is how to do it. 
First create a JavaScript object and then add the properties as header values;

```
    var headers = {};
    if (condition1) {
        headers.FirstHeaderName = 'header value is here';
    }
    if (condition2) {
        headers.SecondHeaderName = 'header value is here';
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: headers
    });
```